# How to create a chat group

Tags: support, chat

How do i create private chat group and invite chat users.
I can't see any menu items, that shows chat or something like that.

Comment: As a normal user you can't have absolute private chatrooms but you might want to checkout [Gallery Chat Rooms](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All chat-rooms can be seen and entered by anyone with chat-privilege.
Still, you can restrict who may write.
Here you go:

Click on "StackExchange" in the top-left, and then on "chat":

[image]

On the chatrooms-list, go to the bottom and choose "create new room":

[image]

On the create-room-page, choose name, description and either public (all users with chat-privilige may write) or gallery (The room owners decide who may write).

[image]

Here a link to a list of all chat- and other communications-privileges (last privilege at 1000):
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=communication