# Why can't I create a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I have followed the instructions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275744/674039) but I see no "create a new room" button, only the "show frozen/deleted rooms" button.

[image: screencap]

Comment: On mobile *Create room* is in the burger menu. On desktop *Create a new room* is at the bottom right beneath the room list. Do those not work?

Comment: No.  Added a screenshot of where the button should be...

Comment: Hmm I see one there :oS

Comment: Hmm, Did you angry any of the moderators who banned you or did you angry the Feeds that auto banned you?

Comment: No, not that I know of.

Comment: @BhargavRao feeds that auto ban?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Nope, Was just pullin wim's leg. AFAIK, only those diamond mods can ban and un-ban users. and users are unbanned only after speaking to mods in chat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Creating a chat room requires 100 reputation on that site (ref: [priviliges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). If you have sufficient rep but still can't create a chat room, your account may be sanctioned.

To see if your account is sanctioned, you can navigate manually to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new  - instead of displaying the form to create a new chat room, a sanctioned account will return the response:

> You are currently banned from creating new rooms.

A user could be banned from creating chat rooms without any moderators involved due to the actions of an R.O. (*room owner*) in the chat. Room owners have the power to kick users out of chat rooms. Unlike diamond moderators, room owners are not elected by the community, and they may not always have the best interests of the community in mind. In practice, that means a room owner can kick out other users for whatever reason they feel like.

If you're kicked from rooms three times within 24 hrs the system imposes a restriction permanently preventing you from creating chat rooms. There is no indication in the UI that you have a ban, and you might not receive any notification or communication about that. **You can speak to a moderator to have the ban lifted.**

Comment: Just to note - this had nothing to do with a moderator. If you're kicked from rooms three times within 24hrs the system imposes a restriction preventing you from creating rooms until a moderator manually removes it (which I see has already been done)

Comment: There is no indication in the UI that you have a ban, and you might not receive any notification or communication about that <-- am I the only who thinks that's a flawed approach?

Comment: "the ban can be permanent" @JonClements Is that true?

Comment: @deW1: Yeah the whole thing seems extremely underhanded and shady to me.

Comment: @JonClements  Are you sure about that?   I think I've only ever been kicked from a chat room once, surely not three times within 24 hrs.

Comment: @wim absolutely sure.

Comment: Bhargav♦ commented above that "only those diamond mods can ban and un-ban users".  So was he incorrect about that?

Comment: @wim mods can only issue full chat bans (eg: can't use it at all) which are timed and you get notice when trying to join chat.

Comment: This is a  bad advise. Users with less than 100 reputation [can also view this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361746/why-can-i-not-create-a-chat-room-in-software-engineering) and think they can create a new room. **They can't**.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating The advice appears to be fine to me, it is _specifically_ explaining how to detect if you have a chat room creation _ban_. It does not attempt to give any advice on what gives the right to access the page or _what you should do if it returns an error rather than the aforementioned ban notice_. Just because it doesn't answer every case doesn't make it bad advice, if you have something to add for another case you can add another answer.

Comment: Presently i think there is a problem this link says so : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/save

Comment: @wim Your answer has an inaccuracy. Moderators can *not* explicitly issue a ban on a user creating chat rooms. We can suspend a user from chat completely, but not separately apply the restriction on creating rooms. As far as I'm aware, the only way that the chat room creation ban can be triggered is for the user to be kicked from one or more chat rooms 3 or more times within 24  hours. They can be kicked by ROs, moderators, or CMs. Moderators can manually remove the chat room creation ban, but not add it.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the info, have tried to edit out that inaccuracy. Since this stuff is not really documented it's guesswork for a regular user what was actually going on, I've only my own anecdotal experience and random comments from mods to go off..  seems like a pretty weird "feature" of the chat tbh